# Почему при скрытии элементов на нижнем уровне скрывается верхний?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

**SidebarComponent.vue**

```
<script setup>

import SidebarNavigationComponent
  from "./Navigation/SidebarNavigationComponent.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='sidebar__wrapper'>
      <SidebarNavigationComponent />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**SidebarNavigationComponent.vue**

```
<script setup>

import {
  reactive
} from "vue";
import SidebarNavigationListComponent
  from "./SidebarNavigationListComponent.vue";

const items = reactive([
  {
    'label': 'Dashboard',
    'link': '#',
    'items': [],
  },
  {
    'label': 'UI',
    'link': '#',
    'items': [
      {
        'label': 'Tables',
        'link': '#',
        'items': [],
      },
      {
        'label': 'Buttons',
        'link': '#',
        'items': [
          {
            'label': 'Tables',
            'link': '#',
            'items': [],
          },
          {
            'label': 'Buttons',
            'link': '#',
            'items': [],
          },
          {
            'label': 'Forms',
            'link': '#',
            'items': [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        'label': 'Forms',
        'link': '#',
        'items': [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'label': 'Typography',
    'link': '#',
    'items': [],
  },
]);
</script>

<template>
  <nav class='sidebar-navigation'>
    <SidebarNavigationListComponent
      :items='items'
    />
  </nav>
</template>
```

**SidebarNavigationListComponent.vue**

```
<script setup>
import SidebarNavigationItemComponent
  from "./SidebarNavigationItemComponent.vue";

const props = defineProps(['items'])
</script>

<template>
  <ul class='sidebar-navigation__list'>
    <SidebarNavigationItemComponent
        v-for='(item, index) in items'
        :key='index'
        :label='item.label'
        :link='item.link'
        :items='item.items'
    />
  </ul>
</template>
```

**SidebarNavigationItemComponent.vue**

```
<script setup>

import SidebarNavigationListComponent
  from "./SidebarNavigationListComponent.vue";
import {
  ref
} from "vue";

const props = defineProps(['label', 'link', 'items', 'depth']);
const showChildrenItems = ref(false);

const toggleShowChildrenItems = () => {
  showChildrenItems.value = !showChildrenItems.value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <li class='sidebar-navigation__item' @click='toggleShowChildrenItems()'>
    <a v-if='props.items.length === 0' :href='props.link'>{{ props.label }}</a>
    <span v-else>{{ props.label }}</span>

    <SidebarNavigationListComponent
        v-show='showChildrenItems'
        v-if='props.items.length > 0'
        :items='props.items'
    />
  </li>
</template>
```

Структура папок:

```
- src
-- components
-- App.vue
--- Sidebar
---- Navigation
----- SidebarNavigationComponent.vue
----- SidebarNavigationItemComponent.vue
----- SidebarNavigationListComponent.vue
---- SidebarComponent.vue
---- SidebarLogoComponent.vue
```

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Раскрываю второй вложенный, скрывается верхний, открываю снова, все показываются. Как будто `showChildrenItems` не персональный для компонентов. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

У тега `<ul>` разрешаются только подтеги `<li>`. Поэтому нужно так:

```html
<template>
  <ul class='sidebar-navigation__list'>
    <li is="vue:SidebarNavigationItemComponent"
        v-for='(item, index) in items'
        :key='index'
        :label='item.label'
        :link='item.link'
        :items='item.items'
    ></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: спасибо за - is="vue:Component" - для меня из разряда "ачтотакможнобыло?" - обычно юзаю как в доках - <component :is="определяю и т.д."...>